# Visual Studio Code SQL results dock to bottom

Tags: ssms, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to dock the SQL queries results to bottom in VS Code, as we see at SSMS. In old versions of VS Code I could do it, but I don't know what happened. The results can be moved only to left/right of window now, and the results view are awful in this way.

I want to make the VS Code SQL results disposed like this:

[image]

But I have only this on VS Code:

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Go to View -> Toggle Editor Group Layout

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-develop-use-vscode

Comment: Is there a way to make the 'Two Rows' Editor Layout the default for a SQL file type via the settings.json file or some other method?

Comment: @AlecThomas this will be in a future update apparently: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-mssql/issues/1665

Answer (score 19):

Following works on Mac :

Go to Menu > View > Editor Layout > Flip Layout.

Comment: Works on Windows, too.

Comment: If I got a penny every time I come back to this answer, I'll be millionaire.
And to complement this masterpiece, the shortcut is: Shift + Alt + 0 (zero)

Answer (score 14):

**As of December 2020**

---

View → Editor Layout → Two Rows

Comment: PSA: This solution is working fine on the most recent version of VS Code on Windows 10 (as of 2022-08-19).

Answer (score 10):

I don't see that option on Windows though. But you can just flip the layout by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd>

Answer (score 5):

All you have to do is add this in the **`settings.json`** file you're using:

```
"workbench.editor.openSideBySideDirection": "down",
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also simple click on results tab and drag to bottom of source code window or anywhere else you want, no need to use menus really.